# Mule ESB monitoring

Tags: monitoring, zabbix, mule-esb

I need to make Zabbix monitor Mule messages.
To be more precise I need to make Zabbix check if Mule messages are being read.

Are there any ways to do that?

I was trying to Google out something like a command line interface to see messages, but couldn't find anything like it.

Comment: Not really a Zabbix question - you need some way to get that information in an automated way, then it can be easily added in Zabbix.

Comment: Any suggestions of how I could do it? I'm totally new to Mule ESB

Comment: Sorry, not familiar with that product. Hopefully somebody else will be able to help.